# How Create a List of PointPairLists?

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

I have some PointPairLists and I want to Add them to a List; but I face with Exception index out of range for : AllPhiLines[0].Add(Quartz[0]);

I tried below code:

```
        PointPairList Quartz = new PointPairList(7000);
        PointPairList Calcite = new PointPairList(7000);
        PointPairList Dolomite = new PointPairList(7000);
        double[] XQuartz = { -2.05E+00, -1.05E+00, -4.01E-01, 4.25E-01, 1.31E+00, 2.08E+00 };
        double[] YQuartz = {2.64E+00 ,2.62E+00 ,2.61E+00 ,2.59E+00 ,2.57E+00 ,2.55E+00 };
        double[] XCalcite = {-2.83E-01 ,7.19E-01 ,1.90E+00 ,2.96E+00 ,4.02E+00 ,5.02E+00 ,6.03E+00 ,7.09E+00 };
        double[] YCalcite = {2.71E+00 ,2.69E+00 ,2.68E+00 ,2.66E+00 ,2.64E+00 ,2.62E+00 ,2.60E+00 ,2.58E+00 };
        double[] XDolomite = {1.31E+00 ,2.67E+00 ,4.02E+00 ,5.32E+00 ,6.62E+00 ,7.79E+00 ,9.03E+00 };
        double[] YDolomite = {2.88E+00 ,2.86E+00 ,2.84E+00 ,2.82E+00 ,2.80E+00 ,2.78E+00 ,2.76E+00 };
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            Quartz.Add(XQuartz[i], YQuartz[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            Calcite.Add(XCalcite[i], YCalcite[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            Dolomite.Add(XDolomite[i], YDolomite[i]);
        }
        List<PointPairList> AllPhiLines = new List<PointPairList>();
        AllPhiLines[0].Add(Quartz[0]);
        AllPhiLines[0].Add(Calcite[0]);
        AllPhiLines[0].Add(Dolomite[0]);
        LineItem AllPhiLinesCurve = pane1.AddCurve("Phi", AllPhiLines[0], Color.Gray, SymbolType.None)
```

hope anyone help me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllPhiLines` does not contain any values yet, so you cannot address item 0. After creating `AllPhiLines` you first have to add an item to it, like

```cs
AllPhiLines.Add(new PointPairList(7000));
```